# Google Places API. Получение объектов определённой страны

Tags: google-maps-api

Со скрипом въезжаю в Google Places API.

- Получил "Places API for Web" key
- Добавил кредитку к Google аккаунту

Планирую использовать в Android, но пока тренируюсь на запросах в браузере.
Делаю такой вот запрос:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=53.428255,-7.937216&radius=300000&types=point_of_interest&sensor=true&key=MY_API_KEY

Получаю вот такой ответ с 20 объектами:

[image]

Вопрос №1:

Если мне нужно будет на карте отобразить, к примеру, все кемпинги Ирландии, то на каждую порцию из 20 объектов мне нужно будет делать отдельный запрос?

Вопрос №2:

Как делать поиск по конкретной стране, а не по размеру радиуса вокруг выбранной точки?

Comment: Вопрос 1 -  Вроде Да, Вопрос 2 - Вроде никак

Comment: Если первый вопрос "Да", то так и разориться не долго при новых-то ценах  на Google Maps.

Comment: А какова цена там? Как то хотел приложение делать с google place, но потом вроде передумал

Comment: Знаю только что цены резко взлетели с июля. Мне-то всё равно, я делаю проект для колледжа. Я так, в принципе рассуждаю.